# How to get a Select/Options List if I don't have a Form in the DOM

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

Got the following chunk of Html...

```
<div style="visibility:visible" id="stateProvinceDiv">
  <div id="stateUSALabelDiv"><label for="stateUSAIdSelect">Find Your Bookstore</label></div>
    &nbsp;<select size="1" id="stateUSAIdSelect" name="stateUSAId">
      <option>Loading...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The page/content for the select is generated by javascript functions/calls...
I can fetch the page, so I get a HtmlPage instance.

I can't figure out how to fetch the select/options, given that I don't
have a "form" element in the DOM. Pointers to chnuks of code that
handle this would be appreciated.

The actual Html is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>College Textbooks: College Apparel, College Gifts & Used College Books: eFollett.com</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="From used college books to up-to-date college textbooks and great college gifts like your school?s latest college apparel and more, visit efollett.com."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="college textbooks, used college books, college apparel, college gifts"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/javascript/prototype-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/javascript/Util.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/javascript/flPrototypeHelper.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/css/style1.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body onload="accessibleSelect();" id="global">


<!-- BEGIN COREMETRICS SUPPORT -->
<script language="javascript1.2" src="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/javascript/eluminate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript1.2" src="/wcsstore/HostedStoreFrontAssetStore/javascript/cmdatatagutils_WC.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript1.2" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    cmSetProduction();
    var cm_ClientID="90227440";
    cmCreatePageviewTag("efollett Home Page","10051_HOME",null,null,"10051");
    //]]>     
</script>
<!-- END COREMETRICS -->

<div id="wrap">
    <!-- start header -->    
    <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="header">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="skip_to_content" align="left" valign="top">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#content" title="Skip to Content">Skip to Content</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" id="your_account">
                            <ul>
                                <li>&nbsp;<strong>Serving Colleges and Universities</strong> | Online and On Campus</li>      
                                <li> | <a href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/FLLogon?langId=-1&amp;catalogId=10001&amp;storeId=10051" title="Your Account">Your Account</a></li>
                                <li> | Shopping Cart<span class="cart_total">: 0</span> | </li>
                                <li>Subtotal:<span class="subtotal"> $0.00</span>  </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>    
  <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates/storeLogos/411.gif" alt="efollett.com. Online. On Campus." width="272" height="168" border="0" />
  <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates/storeBanners/411.jpg" alt="" width="624" height="168" border="0" /></td>
 </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="top_nav">
        <h2 class="invisible">Site Menu</h2>
     <ul>
            <li><a href="/Home/10001-10051-1?demoKey=d" title="Home">Home</a></li>
           <li>
             | <a href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SpecialOfferView?langId=-1&amp;catalogId=10001&amp;storeId=10051&demoKey=d" title="Special Offers">Special Offers</a>
         </li>
      <li> | <a href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/HelpStoreInfoView?langId=-1&amp;catalogId=10001&amp;storeId=10051&demoKey=d" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li> |<a href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/BuybackInfoView?langId=-1&amp;catalogId=10001&amp;storeId=10051&demoKey=d">Cash For Books</a></li>       
            </ul></td>
    <tr>
    </table>  

        <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr> 
   <!-- START CONTENT -->
      <td align="left" valign="top"><!--intro table-->

        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="899">
          <tr>    
     <td align="left" valign="top" width="203"><img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates/endeca/global/global_merch.jpg" alt="" width="203" height="140" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><h1 class="secondaryPageHeaderHomepage"><a name="content" id="thecontent"></a>

      Welcome to the efollett.com network of online bookstores!</h1>
   <p> efollett.com provides you with access to over 1,200 online bookstores across the United States and Canada so you can quickly locate your campus store. </p><p> Order your college textbooks, used college books and merchandise by shopping your bookstore's online website. Each bookstore selects the college apparel and other products from their store inventory and fulfills the order, so you are actually shopping at your local bookstore. We do it this way because your campus bookstore is the best source for textbooks, college gifts and merchandise specific to your campus.  </p><p><strong>Please locate your college, university or school from our drop down menus below</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="storefinder">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6">
     <tr style="border: none;">
          <td style="border: none;">
        <div id="errorDiv" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;color:red;" class="text">    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left" valign="top"> 
  <!--  <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates/storeLogos/us_university." width="290" border="0" /> -->
  <h2 class="us">U.S. College and Universities</h2>

   <br />
   <div style="visibility:visible" id="stateProvinceDiv">
     <div id="stateUSALabelDiv"><label for="stateUSAIdSelect">Find Your Bookstore</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="stateUSAIdSelect" name="stateUSAId">
      <option>Loading...</option>
     </select>
       </div>
   <br />


   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="institutionUSADiv">
     <div id="institutionUSALabelDiv"><label for="institutionUSAIdSelect">Select Your Institution</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="institutionUSAIdSelect" name="institutionUSAId">
     </select>
       </div>
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="campusUSADiv">
    <div id="campusUSALabelDiv"><label for="campusUSAIdSelect">Select Your Campus</label></div>

     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="campusUSAIdSelect" name="campusUSAId">     
     </select> 
   </div>
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="programUSADiv">
    <div id="programUSALabelDiv"><label for="programUSAIdSelect">Select Your Program</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="programUSAIdSelect" name="programUSAId"></select>
   </div>
   &nbsp;<div id="buttonDivUS"></div>

   <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates//spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" alt="" />

  </td>


 <td align="left" valign="top">
  <h2 class="canada">Canada Colleges and Universities </h2>
  <br />
   <div style="visibility:visible" id='stateProvince2Div'>
     <div id='stateCALabelDiv'><label for="stateCAIdSelect">Find Your Bookstore</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="stateCAIdSelect" name="stateCAId">

      <option>Loading...</option>
     </select>
       </div>
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="institutionCADiv">
     <div id="institutionCALabelDiv"><label for="institutionCAIdSelect">Select Your Institution</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="institutionCAIdSelect"  name="institutionCAId"></select>
       </div>

   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="campusCADiv">
    <div id="campusCALabelDiv"><label for="campusCAIdSelect">Select Your Campus</label></div>
    &nbsp;<select size="1" id="campusCAIdSelect"  name="campusCAId"></select>
   </div>   
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="programCADiv">
    <div id="programCALabelDiv"><label for="programCAIdSelect">Select Your Program</label></div>

     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="programCAIdSelect" name="programCAId"></select>
   </div>
   &nbsp;<div id="buttonDivCA"></div>
   <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates//spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" alt="" />

  </td>

  <td align="left" valign="top"> 
  <h2 class="us">U.S Schools K-12  </h2>
  <br />
   <div style="visibility:visible" id="stateProvince3Div">

     <div id="stateUSK12LabelDiv"><label for="stateUSK12IdSelect">Find Your Bookstore</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="stateUSK12IdSelect" name="stateUSK12Id">
      <option>Loading...</option>
     </select>
       </div>
   <br /> 
   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="institutionUSK12Div">
     <div id="institutionUSK12LabelDiv"><label for="institutionUSK12IdSelect">Select Your Institution</div>

     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="institutionUSK12IdSelect" name="institutionUSK12Id"></select>
       </div>
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="campusUSK12Div">
    <div id="campusUSK12LabelDiv"><label for="campusUSK12IdSelect">Select Your Campus</label></div>
     &nbsp;<select size="1" id="campusUSK12IdSelect" name="campusUSK12Id"></select> 
   </div>
   <br />

   <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  id="programUSK12Div">

    <div id="programUSK12LabelDiv"><label for="programUSK12IdSelect">Select Your Program</label></div>
    &nbsp;<select size="1" id="programUSK12IdSelect" name="programUSK12Id"></select>
      </div>
       &nbsp;<div id="buttonDivK12"></div>
      <img src="http://images.efollett.com/htmlroot/images/templates//spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" alt="" />

     </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(s) { return this.indexOf(s)==0; }

    var uri = '/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StoreFinderAJAX';
    var servletPath = '/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/';
    var pageType = 'FLGStoreCatalogDisplay';
    var catalogId = '10001';
    var categoryId = 'null';
    var langId = '-1';
    var demoKey = 'null';
    var extraParams = 'null'; // only used for User Registration page
    var multiSelect = false;
    var forwardURLLocation = '';

    // This map is used to determine the URI used for forwarding the user
    var forwardPage = Object;
    forwardPage['FLGStoreCatalogDisplay'] =    'StoreCatalogDisplay';
    forwardPage['FLUserSelectSchool'] =    'UserAccountUpdateDemographicsForm';
    forwardPage['FLGBuybackInfoPage'] =    'AboutBuybackView';
    forwardPage['FLEdoptionsDisplayGlobal'] =   'EdoptionSearchView';
    forwardPage['CGSelectStoreDisplay'] =    'CustomtsSelectedStore';
    forwardPage['FLLocateStoreCourseMaterials'] =  'LocateCourseMaterialsView';
    forwardPage['FLGGenMerchDisplay'] =    'CategoryDisplay';

    function onPageLoad() {
    AjaxQueue.setBatchSize(1); 

     getData(buildParms('STATESUS', 'US', 'stateUSAIdSelect'));  
     getData(buildParms('STATESCA','CA', 'stateCAIdSelect'));    
     getData(buildParms('STATESK12','K12', 'stateUSK12IdSelect'));
    }

    accessibleSelect=function(){ 
          var selectedStateUSIndex;
      var selectedInstUSIndex;
      var selectedCampusUSIndex;
      var selectedProgramUSIndex; 

      var selectedStateCAIndex;
      var selectedInstCAIndex;
      var selectedCampusCAIndex;
      var selectedProgramCAIndex; 

      var selectedStateK12Index;
      var selectedInstK12Index;
      var selectedCampusK12Index;
      var selectedProgramK12Index; 

      var stateUSAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("stateUSAIdSelect");                   
            stateUSAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
               callUSStateAjax();
        };
            stateUSAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
               callUSStateAjax();
            };
             function callUSStateAjax() {
       if(selectedStateUSIndex != stateUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
        doAJAXSelect("onStateUSASelect()");
        selectedStateUSIndex = stateUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
        selectedInstUSIndex = '';
        selectedCampusUSIndex = '';
        selectedProgramUSIndex = '';
        }
      }

      var institutionUSAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("institutionUSAIdSelect");                    
        institutionUSAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callInstUSAjax();
            };
            institutionUSAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
               callInstUSAjax();
            };
            function callInstUSAjax() {
       if(selectedInstUSIndex != institutionUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
        doAJAXSelect("onInstituteUSASelect()");
        selectedInstUSIndex = institutionUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
        selectedCampusUSIndex = null;
        selectedProgramUSIndex = null;
       }
      }

            var campusUSAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("campusUSAIdSelect");
            campusUSAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
                 callCampusUSAjax();
        };
        campusUSAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
            callCampusUSAjax();
        };
        function callCampusUSAjax() {
       if(selectedCampusUSIndex != campusUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
              doAJAXSelect("onCampusSelect_USA()");
    selectedCampusUSIndex == campusUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
        selectedProgramUSIndex = null;
          }
      }

            var programUSAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("programUSAIdSelect");
            programUSAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callProgramUSAjax();
        };
        programUSAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callProgramUSAjax();
        };
        function callProgramUSAjax() {
       if(selectedProgramUSIndex != programUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
               doAJAXSelect("onProgramSelect_USA()");
          selectedProgramUSIndex = programUSAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
       }
     }

        var stateCAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("stateCAIdSelect");
        stateCAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callStateCAAjax();
        };
        stateCAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
            callStateCAAjax();
        };

        function callStateCAAjax() {
   if(selectedStateCAIndex != stateCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
    doAJAXSelect("onStateCASelect()");
    selectedStateCAIndex = stateCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
    selectedInstCAIndex = null;
    selectedCampusCAIndex = null;
    selectedProgramCAIndex =null;
    }
  }


  var institutionCAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("institutionCAIdSelect");                    
        institutionCAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callInstCAAjax();
        };
        institutionCAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callInstCAAjax();
        };
        function callInstCAAjax() {
  if(selectedInstCAIndex != institutionCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
   doAJAXSelect("onInstituteCASelect()");
   selectedInstCAIndex = institutionCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
   selectedCampusCAIndex = null;
   selectedProgramCAIndex = null;
  }
    }     


        var campusCAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("campusCAIdSelect");
        campusCAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callCampusCAAjax();
        };
        campusCAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callCampusCAAjax();
        };
        function callCampusCAAjax() {
   if(campusCAIdSelectBox != campusCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
         doAJAXSelect("onCampusSelect_CA()");
    selectedCampusCAIndex == campusCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
    selectedProgramCAIndex = null;
      }
  }



        var programCAIdSelectBox = document.getElementById("programCAIdSelect");
        programCAIdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callProgramCAAjax();
        };
        programCAIdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callProgramCAAjax();
        };
        function callProgramCAAjax() {
   if(selectedProgramCAIndex != programCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
          doAJAXSelect("onProgramSelect_CA()");
          selectedProgramCAIndex = programCAIdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
   }
     }




        var stateUSK12IdSelectBox = document.getElementById("stateUSK12IdSelect");
        stateUSK12IdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callStateK12Ajax();
        };
        stateUSK12IdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callStateK12Ajax();
        };
        function callStateK12Ajax() {
   if(selectedStateK12Index != stateUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
    doAJAXSelect("onStateUSK12Select()");
    selectedStateK12Index = stateUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
    selectedInstK12Index = null;
    selectedCampusK12Index = null;
    selectedProgramK12Index = null;
   }
  }


  var institutionUSK12IdSelectBox = document.getElementById("institutionUSK12IdSelect");                    
        institutionUSK12IdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callInstK12Ajax();
        };
        institutionUSK12IdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callInstK12Ajax();
        };
        function callInstK12Ajax() {
   if(selectedInstK12Index != institutionUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
    doAJAXSelect("onInstituteUSK12Select()");
    selectedInstK12Index = institutionUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
    selectedCampusK12Index = null;
    selectedProgramK12Index = null;
   }
  }



        var campusUSK12IdSelectBox = document.getElementById("campusUSK12IdSelect");
        campusUSK12IdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
            callCampusK12Ajax();
        };
        campusUSK12IdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
           callCampusK12Ajax();
        };
        function callCampusK12Ajax() {
   if(selectedCampusK12Index != campusUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
         doAJAXSelect("onCampusSelect_USK12()");
    selectedCampusK12Index == campusUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
        selectedProgramK12Index = null;
          }
      }


        var programUSK12IdSelectBox = document.getElementById("programUSK12IdSelect");
            programUSK12IdSelectBox.onchange=function(){
                callProgramK12Ajax();
            };
            programUSK12IdSelectBox.onkeyup=function(e){
               callProgramK12Ajax();
            };
            function callProgramK12Ajax() {
       if(selectedProgramK12Index != programUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex) {
              doAJAXSelect("onProgramSelect_USK12()");
                  selectedProgramK12Index = programUSK12IdSelectBox.selectedIndex;
          }
            }
        }

    // Start state
    function onStateUSASelect() { 
                    hideLayer("errorDiv");hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer("campusUSADiv");showLayer("institutionUSADiv");addLoadingOption("institutionUSA"); 
     hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");hideLayer("institutionCADiv");
     hideLayer("programUSK12Div");hideLayer("campusUSK12Div");hideLayer("institutionUSK12Div");
     hideLayer("buttonDivUS");hideLayer("buttonDivCA");hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
     selectFirst("stateCAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateUSK12IdSelect");
     if($('stateUSAIdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("institutionUSADiv"); return; }  
     getData(buildParms('INSTITUTESUS', 'US', 'stateProvinceId='+$('stateUSAIdSelect').value)) ;
    }

    function onStateCASelect() {
     hideLayer("errorDiv");hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");showLayer("institutionCADiv");addLoadingOption("institutionCA");
         hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer("campusUSADiv");hideLayer("institutionUSADiv");
     hideLayer("programUSK12Div");hideLayer("campusUSK12Div");hideLayer("institutionUSK12Div");
     hideLayer("buttonDivUS");hideLayer("buttonDivCA");hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
     selectFirst("stateUSAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateUSK12IdSelect");
     if($('stateCAIdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("institutionCADiv"); return; }
     getData(buildParms('INSTITUTESCA', 'CA', 'stateProvinceId='+$('stateCAIdSelect').value)) ; 
    }

    function onStateUSK12Select() {
     hideLayer("errorDiv");hideLayer("programUSK12Div");hideLayer("campusUSK12Div");showLayer("institutionUSK12Div");addLoadingOption("institutionUSK12");
     hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer("campusUSADiv");hideLayer("institutionUSADiv");
     hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");hideLayer("institutionCADiv");
     hideLayer("buttonDivUS");hideLayer("buttonDivCA");hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
     selectFirst("stateUSAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateCAIdSelect");
     if($('stateUSK12IdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("institutionUSK12Div"); return; }
     getData(buildParms('INSTITUTESK12', 'K12', 'stateProvinceId='+$('stateUSK12IdSelect').value)) ; 
    }
    //End State

    //Start Institute
    function onInstituteUSASelect() {
     hideLayer("errorDiv"); hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer('campusUSADiv');hideLayer('buttonDivUS');
     hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");hideLayer("institutionCADiv");
     hideLayer("programUSK12Div");hideLayer("campusUSK12Div");hideLayer("institutionUSK12Div");
     selectFirst("stateCAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateUSK12IdSelect");
     if($('institutionUSAIdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("campusUSADiv"); return; }
     getData(buildParms('CAMPUSUS','US', 'institutionId='+$('institutionUSAIdSelect').value));
    }

    function onInstituteCASelect() {
     hideLayer("errorDiv");
     hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer("campusUSADiv");hideLayer("institutionUSADiv");
     hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");
     hideLayer("programUSK12Div");hideLayer("campusUSK12Div");hideLayer("institutionUSK12Div");
     selectFirst("stateUSAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateUSK12IdSelect");

     if($('institutionCAIdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("campusCADiv"); return; }
     getData(buildParms('CAMPUSCA','CA','institutionId='+$('institutionCAIdSelect').value));
    }

    function onInstituteUSK12Select() {
     hideLayer("errorDiv");hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer('campusK12Div');hideLayer('buttonDivK12');
     hideLayer("programUSADiv");hideLayer("campusUSADiv");hideLayer("institutionUSADiv");
     hideLayer("programCADiv");hideLayer("campusCADiv");hideLayer("institutionCADiv");
     selectFirst("stateUSAIdSelect");
     selectFirst("stateCAIdSelect");
     if($('institutionUSK12IdSelect').value == '') {clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("campusUSK12Div"); return; }
     getData(buildParms('CAMPUSK12','K12','institutionId='+$('institutionUSK12IdSelect').value));
    }

    // End of Institutions

    // Start Campus

    function onCampusSelect_USA() {
        if($('campusUSAIdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("programUSADiv"); hideLayer("errorDiv");  hideLayer("buttonDivUS"); return; }
        // REMOVE THIS LATER
       clearAJAXTimer();
        getData(buildParms('PROGRAMSUS','US','campusId='+$('campusUSAIdSelect').value + "&institutionId=" +  $('institutionUSAIdSelect').value));
    }

    function onCampusSelect_CA() {
        if($('campusCAIdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("programCADiv"); hideLayer("errorDiv"); hideLayer("buttonDivCA"); return; }
          // REMOVE THIS LATER
          clearAJAXTimer();
          getData(buildParms('PROGRAMSCA','CA', 'campusId='+$('campusCAIdSelect').value + "&institutionId=" +  $('institutionCAIdSelect').value));
    }

    function onCampusSelect_USK12() {
        if($('campusUSK12IdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("programUSK12Div"); hideLayer("errorDiv"); hideLayer("buttonDivK12"); return; }
        // REMOVE THIS LATER
       clearAJAXTimer();
        getData(buildParms('PROGRAMSK12','K12', 'campusId='+$('campusUSK12IdSelect').value + "&institutionId=" +  $('institutionUSK12IdSelect').value));
    }

    // End of Campus

    // Program Select 
    function onProgramSelect_USA() {
      if($('programUSAIdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("buttonDivUS"); return; }
       // REMOVE THIS LATER
      clearAJAXTimer();
      doForward($("programUSAIdSelect").value, null, 'buttonDivUS');
    }

    function onProgramSelect_CA() {
      if($('programCAIdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer(); hideLayer("buttonDivCA"); return; }
      // REMOVE THIS LATER
          clearAJAXTimer();
      doForward($("programCAIdSelect").value, null,'buttonDivCA');
    }

    function onProgramSelect_USK12() {
      if($('programUSK12IdSelect').value == ''){clearAJAXTimer();hideLayer("buttonDivK12"); return; }
      // REMOVE THIS LATER
      clearAJAXTimer();
      doForward($("programUSK12IdSelect").value, null, 'buttonDivK12');
    }
    // End of Program Select.
                                                         // Loading Drop downs starts
    function loadSTATESUS(data, meta) {
       hideLayer("buttonDivUS");
      hideLayer("buttonDivCA");
      hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
      addOptions("stateUSA", data, meta, "stateUSAIdSelect");
    }

    function loadSTATESCA(data, meta) {
      hideLayer("buttonDivUS");
      hideLayer("buttonDivCA");
      hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
      addOptions("stateCA", data, meta, "stateCAIdSelect");
    }

    function loadSTATESK12(data, meta) {
      hideLayer("buttonDivUS");
      hideLayer("buttonDivCA");
      hideLayer("buttonDivK12");
      addOptions("stateUSK12", data, meta, "stateUSK12IdSelect");
    }

    function loadINSTITUTESUS(data, meta) {
```

Comment: huuge post, can't you compact the information into the problem itself?

Comment: hi... 

htmlunit allows you to test, and to manipulate the page. i can use htmlunit to get the page. but i can't figure out how to create the correct method/instance to grab the option list of the given select, because e i can't create an instance of the HtmlForm. 

All the examples that I've seen online, imply that you need to create the HtmlForm, and then invoke that to get the "getSelectedByName()..." 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the select with prototype and the id of the select.

```
$('stateUSAIdSelect');
```

Or the options with a css rule

```
$$('#stateUSAIdSelect option');
```

What are you actually trying to do with them?

UPDATE:

Sorry, I misunderstood the question I think. You're trying to figure out how to test those elements with htmlunit?

To get the select you can use `getHtmlElementById`

```
page.getHtmlElementById("stateUSAIdSelect");
```

From there you can call `getChildNodes` to grab all the options from the select.

The javadoc for htmlunit outlines a whole bunch of other methods you should be able to use as well http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi john...

htmlunit allows you to test, and to manipulate the page. i can use htmlunit to get the page. but i can't figure out how to create the correct method/instance to grab the option list of the given select, because e i can't create an instance of the HtmlForm. All the examples that I've seen online, imply that you need to create the HtmlForm, and then invoke that to get the "getSelectedByName()..."

thanks

Comment: Ya, sorry, I thought you were just trying to select the elements with javascript. I've updated my answer a little bit, hopefully that helps.